Stability of first eigenfunction of Laplace-Beltrami in spherical caps
Let us denote $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ by $(x',x_n)$, where $x' \in \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$.
Let $\Omega_L := \{x : |x| = 1, x_n > L|x'|\} \subset \mathbb{S}^{n-1}.$
Then, we consider $\phi_L$ to be the first eigenfunction of the (negative) Laplace-Beltrami operator with zero Dirichlet boundary conditions in $\Omega_L$, normalized in $L^2$. For instance, we can characterize $\phi_L$ as the minimizer of
$$\min\limits_{\|u\|_{L^2(\Omega_L)} = 1}\int_{\Omega_L}|\nabla u|^2.$$
What I want to prove is that
$$\|\phi_{L_1} - \phi_{L_2}\|_{L^2(\mathbb{S}^{n-1})} \leq C|L_1 - L_2|,$$
at least for small values of $L_1$ and $L_2$. I believe that the dependence of $\phi_L$ on $L$ is actually analytic, but Lipschitz continuity is enough for what I need.
So far, I have the following:

In dimension $n = 2$, in polar coordinates, we can write the eigenfunctions as
$$\phi_L(\theta) = \sqrt{\frac{2\beta}{\pi}}(\cos(\beta\theta))_+,$$
with
$$\tan(\frac{\pi}{2\beta}) = \frac{1}{L},$$
and the stability result follows by a simple computation.

First attempt using special functions: In general, using spherical coordinates (and axial symmetry) we can write $\phi_L$ as the solution to the ODE
$$\phi_L''+(n-2)\cot(\theta)\phi_L' + \beta(\beta+n-2)\phi_L = 0,$$
with $\phi(0) = 1$ and $\phi(\theta_0) = 0$, where $\theta_0$ corresponds to the boundary condition $x_n = L|x'|$. From here, when $n = 2$ it is easy to compute $\phi_L$ explicitly.
If $n \geq 3$, one can still write the solution to this ODE as a linear combination of associated Legendre functions (online ODE solvers do that), and here I get completely lost on how to use the boundary conditions to determine what the coefficients are, and also how to see from the definition of these special functions that the variation with respect to the aperture angle is Lipschitz.

Second attempt using perturbation theory: From the standard variational arguments (simply connected manifold with boundary), the first eigenvalue is simple, so there will be no branch points. Then, we can use something like Theorem 1.8 of Chapter VII of Kato's Perturbation Theory for Linear Operators. The problem here is that I'm not familiar at all with the language of operators and don't know how to check if the hypotheses of the theorem are verified (I'm sure they are, because the Laplacian is everything good you could hope for, and this is just a spherical cap varying the angle, nothing fancy).


I imagine both approaches work, and I would greatly appreciate any help to work out the details, or references that are accessible to someone coming from an elliptic PDE background.

Have a look at this paper: A Global Lipschitz Continuity Result for
a Domain Dependent Dirichlet Eigenvalue
Problem for the Laplace Operator, Pier Domenico Lamberti and Massimo Lanza de Cristoforis, ZAA 24 (2005), No. 2, 277–304. It is a general result on Lipschitz varying domains. I am sure there are many others (I remember some papers by D. Daners on the topic).
